# Not getting any form element on the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I designed one form and declared some input elements inside this but i am not getting any form on my webpage while i am running using c# ASP.NET.The following is my code file.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Text1
        {
            width: 219px;
            height: 31px;
        }
        #File1
        {
            height: 22px;
        }
        #Text2
        {
            width: 204px;
            height: 39px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <h1>3 TIRE ARCHITECTURE</h1>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:FormView ID="Record" runat="server" Height="117px" Width="492px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name:"></asp:Label>
                <input id="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input id="Text2" type="text" runat="server" />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#66FF66" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Insert" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BusinessLayer;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsBusiness objBusiness = new clsBusiness();
        GridView1.DataSource = objBusiness.LoadCustomer();
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsBusiness objBusiness = new clsBusiness();
        objBusiness.AddNewUser(Request.Form["Text1"], Request.Form["Text2"]);
        clearAll();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    public void clearAll()
    {
        Request.Form["Text1"] = "";
        Request.Form["Text2"] = "";
    }
}
```

I am new to c# .NET frame work so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your pagename is `Default.aspx` and it is inherting `_Default` its wrong. Please change it to `Default`

Comment: But gridview part is coming only the input fields are not coming.

Comment: try chaning that and check

Comment: What exactly do you see? Can you post the results of `View Page Source`?

Comment: I assume there is a reason you aren't using `<asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you have an `id` attribute but no `name` attribute for your form elements. The `name` attribute is used for `HTTPRequest`

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text"  runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I added your code in my page and I was able to see the form.

As per the latest comment by `Guruprasad` I am adding my whole code here also.

[ASPX js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8d4s28y/)

also the code behind:-

```
public partial class Default_T : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsBusiness objBusiness = new clsBusiness();
    GridView1.DataSource = objBusiness.LoadCustomer();
    GridView1.DataBind();


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsBusiness objBusiness = new clsBusiness();
    objBusiness.AddNewUser(Request.Form["Text1"], Request.Form["Text2"]);
    clearAll();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
public void clearAll()
{
    Request.Form["Text1"] = "";
    Request.Form["Text2"] = "";
}
```

}

[image: Image screenshot]

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because the code behind file might be declared like this `public class partial _Default : Page`

Comment: But what OP has written is syntatically wrong and it should be corrected and move ahead

Comment: @ nad :After adding your linr again it gave me the following error.

 ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class.

Comment: I just created a website in VS and with all default values and even am getting the same thing!! It actually extracts as `_Default` for the `inherit` property!! Try creating one!! Just a point to note!! No offense meant!!

Comment: @satya: actually your cs is written so revert your changes back. 
GuruprasadRao: Yes got it

Comment: @ nad : the error is coming at line 'public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page`.Please cehck my updated post again.

Comment: There is no problem with the `Inherits`. Look at the codebehind. It is `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: @satya: did you revert back the aspx code to `_default` what I told in my post

Comment: This has nothing to do with `inherits` attribute. It is alright with `_Default`.

Comment: I already revert back and also getting one output inside gridview so i dont think it is problem with `inherits`.

Comment: @satya: so what is the current issue now ? also try debugging your code for more information that what is going on noq

Comment: @ nad : i need to do some insert operation with that form and the form is not coming at all.That is the issue.

Comment: @nad I suggest it will be good if you put the exact code of `aspx` and `cs` too in the answer!! Does it look same as OPs code in question!!